# TRIAC Failure - Short between input and gate?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pic, opto-isolator, triac, troubleshooting

I am having a spot of trouble with a TRIAC (T2535-600G) whose gate is triggered by a PIC microcontroller (PIC12F1501)through an opto-isolator (MOC3063SM).

Normally, the TRIAC, labeled U2 in the diagram below, will pass 120VAC to my output, labeled HEATER_OUT, when the gate is triggered if measured with respect to AC neutral. Recently, I had one that was wired incorrectly. From what I was told, since I was not there when it happened, was that the AC neutral was connected to HEATER_OUT pin by accident. Once the wiring was corrected, there was a constant 68VAC being supplied to HEATER_OUT without any output from the PIC to the opto-isolator.

My initial thought was that the TRIAC had simply failed in a manner that allowed half the voltage to pass through it without a signal to the gate due to a short between 120VAC hot and neutral through the TRIAC. I was surprised however when I cut the output of the TRIAC from the circuit and was still measuring 68VAC at the output (HEATER_OUT). At this point I disconnected the connections between the PIC and the opto-isolator but still no change. Only until I severed the connection to the gate of the TRIAC from the circuit did the voltage finally diminish to 1VAC.

Is it possible that the 120VAC input is somehow passing from the input of the TRIAC through the gate???

Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful at replicating the failure after multiple attempts. Also, while wired incorrectly, the circuit was hipot tested at 1500V with 1 second ramp up, dwell, and ramp down checking for 4mA leakage current or greater which it passed.

Any insight to help understanding what happened to my TRIAC would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time.

[image: Complete Circuit with Alterations (RED)]

Comment: Disabled Triac can give faulty readings from leakage current into 10Meg DMM unless loaded.

Comment: Hey Tony, thanks for commenting! Agreed, something I've definitely seen before. Normally, with a functional circuit, (without activating the gate of the TRIAC) my meter will pick up about 18VAC on the output when no load is connected and then it drops to 0VAC when i connect the 8Ω load. For this case however, something was different. Once again, without energizing the gate of the TRIAC, there was enough voltage across the 8Ω resistive element to allow it to overheat and nearly catch fire. My main goal is understand what happened so I can hopefully prevent repeat events in the future.

Comment: I'd also like to include some more info about how the above circuit works. The top portion of the circuit simply converts and chops my 120VAC input down to 24VDC & 5VDC. The 5VDC is used to supply temperature feedback to my PIC through a thermistor. The 24VDC powers a photo-eye which directs the 24VDC to the PROD_DET input to act as a "turn heater on signal". The AMBER & RED outputs are for LED visual indicators. The actual output is driven to the opto-isolator for a duration based upon the temperature feedback.